# How to get value of a Spark dataset column value to use it dynamically in SQL Query?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, dataset

I have a Dataset DS1 which is having one column value "LEVEL". I want to check this column value and get another column "COMPANIES" which is an array and based on some business logic, I have to update the values.

For this update operation, I am using withColumn() method.

```
DS1.withColumn("COMPANIES", functions.when(functions.col("LEVEL").gt(1), someMethod(sparkSession, functions.col("COMPANIES"), functions.col("LEVEL"))).otherwise(functions.col("value")));
```

inside the someMethod(), I am trying to use the Column as parameters.

```
    private int[] someMethod(SparkSession sparkSession, Column companies, Column Level) {
        
        String query = "Select cs.level from DS1 cs inner join DS2 cp on cs.level=" + (Level.minus(1)) + " and cs.company_private_id=ANY(" + companies + ")";
        
        sparkSession.sql(query);
List<Integer> list = sparkSession.sql(query).collectAsList().get(0).getList(0);
        
        return list.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
    }
```

I could not get the values for the variables Level, companies as they are of Column type. How to do the logic here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data type for levels is Integer. If type is something else change row.getInteger(0) to row.getDecimal(0) for data type bigDecimal.

```
List<Row> dataSet = sparkSession.sql(query).collectAsList();

List<Integer> levels = dataSet.stream().map(row -> row.getInteger(0)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```